# Linq to Find and eliminate duplicate file names

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008

Hi I am using linq to Eliminate the Duplicate File Names...

These are the conditions of a `FileData` to be Collected. but how to get Distinct values only by comparing its FileName that is `f.Name` Property.

I tried

```
IEnumerable<FileData> files = FastDirectoryEnumerator
                    .EnumerateFiles(myDirectory.FullName, "*.zip", 
                     SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(f => f.Size / 1024 > 750)
                    .Where(f => !f.Name.EndsWith(".reg.zip"))
                    .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("2001"));
```

From this Can i Get the Unique File names..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) method:

```
IEnumerable<FileData> dats = FastDirectoryEnumerator
    .EnumerateFiles(myDirectory.FullName, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => f.Size / 1024 > 750)
    .Where(f => !f.Name.EndsWith(".reg.zip"))
    .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("2001"))
    .GroupBy(f => f.Name)
    .Select(g => g.First());
```

Or in query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<FileData> dats = 
    from f in FastDirectoryEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(…)
    where f.Size / 1024 > 750 &&
          !f.Name.EndsWith(".reg.zip") &&
          f.Name.StartsWith("2001") &&
    group f by f.Name into g
    select g.First();
```

This will return the first `FileData` with each name. If you want to get just the unique `Name` values, it's actually a bit easier:

```
IEnumerable<string> dats = FastDirectoryEnumerator
    .EnumerateFiles(myDirectory.FullName, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(f => f.Size / 1024 > 750)
    .Where(f => !f.Name.EndsWith(".reg.zip"))
    .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("2001"))
    .Select(f => f.Name)
    .Distinct();
```

Or in query syntax:

```
IEnumerable<string> dats = 
    (from f in FastDirectoryEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(…)
     where f.Size / 1024 > 750 &&
           !f.Name.EndsWith(".reg.zip") &&
           f.Name.StartsWith("2001") &&
     select f.Name)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: oh , we using `GroupBy` for organizing all the files with same name and taking the `First()` one out... isn't it...?? GOT it.. :-)

Comment: @Gokul Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: In case of distinct... Actually I tried the `Distinct` but how it will compare it.. ? based on what?? I tried it. no success. getting twice / more of `FileData` which is duplicate in another directory....

Comment: @Gokul notice the `Select(f => f.Name)` / `select f.Name`. If all you want is the distinct names, you can pull out the names first, *then* use `Distinct()`. If you want to return the whole `FileData`, then you need to use `GroupBy`

Comment: oh... yea.. got it.. but the final list we are getting will be the List of `FileData` or only the collection of `f.Name` data ??? sorry if i asked wrong... :-P